# Serial Port Communication understanding

Tags: matlab, io, sensors

i need some help understanding a specific serial port connection from a sensor. I need to read data from the sensor and make some calculations in matlab or c++ (i will decide later)

The manufacturer only gives a chart with the following details:

> Sensor Serial Port
>
> Pin Number Mode Pin Description
>
> 1. I Trigger Input
> 2. I RS-232 Receive
> 3. O RS-232 Transmit
> 4. PWR Sensor Power (DTR)
> 5. PWR/GND Signal Ground
> 6. - Not Used (Reserved)
> 7. - Not Used (Reserved)
> 8. I/O RS-485 B Signal Pin
> 9. I/O RS-485 A Signal Pin**

So my question is: OK i know that pin 2 is used to receive data but how am i going to decode the volts stream into integers for example for my program? Also, i know that pin 4 gives power to the sensor. How do i know how many volts it has to give? Generally how am i going to learn all these details since the manufacturer does not give it?

Do you think Serial Port Analyzer Software will help?

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: Anyone who knows????

Do you think i need a serial port analyzer or a logic analyzer?? how can i read data transmitted in binary??? maybe if i read a data stream, i could understand which bits match my data because i know exactly the values bandwidth...

Comment: There must be more documentation available than the pin layout. What device are you trying to use?

Comment: this is the sensor i am trying to use: http://hollandscientific.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/Manual.pdf

Comment: and here: http://hollandscientific.com/wp-content/uploads/files/GeoSCOUT.pdf   in page 15 you can see the pins of rs232 cable.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to search for "DE-9 pinout YourSensorNameHere" in google or [This page](http://airborn.com.au/serial/rs232.html) might be of some use to you. With most RS-232 you only need pins 2,3 and 5. With out more specifics about your sensor there isn't much SO can do for you.